# firebase googlesignin error in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, firebase-authentication

this is the function which is called when user click a button from the html page.

this function is in auth.js which is called in server.js page

auth.js

```
 const firebase = require("firebase");
 static googleSignIn(req,res){      

    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()).
    then( (result) => {
        console.log(result.credential.idToken);
        firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true).then( (token) => {
            console.log(token);
        });

    }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });

}
```

i get this error

```
code: 'auth/operation-not-supported-in-this-environment',
message:
'This operation is not supported in the environment this application is 
running on. "location.protocol" must be http, https or chrome-extension and 
web storage must be enabled
```

is there any way to send html request and get the token as response ,or any alternative way.please help

Answer (score 0):

That error message is trying to tell you that Firebase Authentication client libraries don't work in a node.js environment.  They're only supported for web browser clients.

[Read more here.](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/558#issuecomment-372058769)

Comment: ohk , so any server side authentication available for googlesignin ? any other way like processing on html and sending token as response to the server ?